# How can I switch database when using Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

In my application.properties file I have the following line:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.50.25.20:5432/db1
```

The problem is that I also have another database with the same tables called db2. How can I switch to db2 programmatically?

Answer (score -1):

It might be easier to just set up two separate applications and separate urls for them. Spring will initialize the datasource on startup.  It is possible to have two datasources in your spring app, but it's difficult to use the same connection pool or entities with different datasources.